# How to clear the settings of default app to the files with special file extension?

Tags: macos, finder

I set the default app to open the files with special file extension by mistake: the app could not open them at all for they're only file fragments (or, say, no app can until I combine them as one file). 

So I want to clean the settings of default app (set no default app), but no solutions found. Any ideas? Hope for your answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's free, and configurable per extension.

http://www.rubicode.com/Software/RCDefaultApp/

Comment: The app you mentioned sounds interesting. I tried it and set the default app to 'DoNothing', then uninstall it; then the default app is null, and no app will try to open the 'special' files. Nice solution, but not the best one. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

For changing default app (no option to clean the setting tho):

1. If you don't have a file with that specific extension - create one.
2. Right click on it -> get info.
3. Set "Open with" and click "Change All" button right under it.

All files with that extension will now be opened by that app.

Comment: OMG. Then I could not clean the setting of default app? What sad story.

Comment: I have a question: where is the setting stored? a plist file? or not?

Comment: I guess so, but couldn't find the correct file atm. Anyway, IIRC preferences are now cached and I've seen some people having problems figuring out proper plist files for their needs :/